# Moving DotNetNuke from Local to Host AND not effect production Database

Tags: .net, sql-server, deployment, dotnetnuke, setup-deployment

So I have a "good problem" to have, which I and my team have not been able to find the solution to. I developed our current website on the .Net CMS DotNetNuke, using the client's database which has now been updated twice, thus my database is outdated and would cause thousands of new changes to be lost if I were to directly move my website from my localhost to their production server. My question is, is there a way where I can isolate (or determine) only the changes in the files, and database which have been altered during the development, and only move those particular files/tables ? The goal is to seamlessly transition my local development into their production, without losing any of their recent database updates. Thanks for reading - Justin

P.S. : While I was creating their new website on the front-end, they've been creating new modules and tools on their live site, hence why the database was updated twice during production.

Edit:

More detailed of the problem:

Say I designed your website on the front-end. But during production you were making hundreds (if not thousands) of changes a week on the back end. Thus, during my production of the front-end, my back-end (the database in this case) has become outdated and does not reflect what you're currently running on your production server. So to avoid losing all the thousands of changes you made during the front-end production, how can we marry both the front and back-end together WITHOUT losing changes in either. My best guess is to isolate what's the actual changes that were made on the front (via files or/and DB tables) and only upload those, OR is there a uniformed accepted technique for doing such a marriage.

Comment: this is pretty broad and involved to solve, but if you happen to have access to the literal database (or can get a backup of the database and restore it) you can use tools such as Redgate's SQL Compare, or some of the SSDT tools built into visual studio.  You can use these tools to determine all of the differences between two specified databases (your local compared to the customer's database), which could get you to a starting point of evaluating what needs to be changed.

Comment: Gotcha, so really, there is no defined technique for solving the problem ?

Comment: Well I think it would really depend on the situation.  Your question is quite abstract so it's hard to say for sure.  But I (in my limited knowledge) am leaning toward no.

Comment: Let me add some more detailed edits, 1 second

Comment: I don't know if it will help with visibility or not, but the additional tag of [tag:deployment] might be useful

Comment: I added the tag, can I get a upvote to help as well ? @Kritner

Answer (score 0):

I would start by:

1. Backup the production Database
2. Restore that database in a local environment (not over your existing DB)
3. Connect your local site to that database to see what changes you made do, or don't work.

If in your development you also made database changes, you hopefully scripted those changes out.... If not, you're likely going to want to use some SQL tools to compare database structure, and compare database content, to see if there are changes necessary to sync the two.